# Why does $n$ always divide this sum?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

If we assume $m=p_1^{a_1}\cdots p_s^{a_s}, n=p_1^{b_1}\cdots p_s^{b_s}p_{s+1}^{b_{s+1}}\cdots p_t^{b_t}$, where $0<a_i<b_j$, $p_j$ are different primes($i=1,\cdots,s; j=1,\cdots, t$). Then define
$$A=\binom{n}{m}-\sum_{i=1}^s\binom{n/p_i}{m/p_i}+\sum_{i\not=j}^s\binom{n/p_ip_j}{m/p_ip_j}-\cdots.$$
I discovered that $n|A$.

For example,
$$8|\binom{8}{4}-\binom{4}{2};$$
$$60|\binom{60}{30}-\binom{30}{15}-\binom{20}{10}-\binom{12}{6}+\binom{10}{5}+\binom{6}{3}+\binom{4}{2}-\binom{2}{1}.$$

I wonder how to prove this and whether this definition $A$ had been defined anywhere.

Any problem possibly related to this one would be of great help. I want to know this more than the proof.

Comment: The alternating sums suggest you're counting something via inclusion-exclusion.  The question is, what, and why does it come in groups of $n$?

Comment: Thanks so much. I think I know how to prove this now.

Comment: Good. If you do know how to prove it, let me encourage you to write up your proof and post it as an answer.

Comment: My answer updated in case you are interested.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comment. This is my proof.

Assume you have $n$ empty spaces to put $A$ or $B$ in. If the number of $A$ you have is exactly $m$, then of course you have $\binom{n}{m}$ ways to put them.

Now you want to delete all the sequences which are periodic, like $ABABAB$ or $ABBABB$. The first one has the period of 2 and the second one has the period of 3. It is obvious that the period should be a divisor of $n$, and the number of the sequences with period $p_i$ should be $\binom{n/p_i}{m/p_i}$. With the hint of inclusion-exclusion, the number of aperiodic sequences should be $A$ defined above.

Now since you can do $n$ cyclic permutations to a sequence, you can prove $n|A$ if

(i) the permutation of an aperiodic sequence is still aperiodic;

(ii) the permutation of a periodic sequence is still periodic.